# Search contact name using partial info

Tags: vba, outlook

I search a contact and get its email address.
Using Outlook local contact folder (now its name is People I think).

```vb
Public Sub ShowContactEmail()

Dim myContacts As Folder
Dim myfilter As String
Dim filteredItems As Outlook.Items
Dim myName As String
myName = "John Doe"

Set myContacts = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
Set filteredItems = myContacts.Items

myfilter = "[FirstName] = " & myName & " Or [LastName] = " & myName & " Or [FullName] = " & myName

For Each myItem In filteredItems.Restrict(myfilter)
    If (myItem.Class = olContact) Then
    Debug.Print myItem.Email1Address
    End If
Next
 
End Sub
```

It works if name is exactly as in contact folder.
If I look for "Doe" won't find anything.

How to do a partial search? Tried to use "like" and "wildcards".

Also not sure if I have to search in FirstName, Lastname or FullName.

This PC is used by several people and new contact details are not always input as I want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.restrict#using-variables-as-part-of-the-filter) correctly you can use `char(32)` as a 'wildcard' in your search

Answer (score 0):

When matching string properties, you can use either a pair of single quotes ('), or a pair of double quotes ("), to delimit a string that is part of the filter. Typically in VBA `Chr(34)` function is used which stands for double quotes. For example:

```
myfilter = "[FirstName] = " & Chr(34) & myName & Chr(34) & " Or [LastName] = " & Chr(34) & myName & Chr(34) & " Or [FullName] = " & Chr(34) & myName & Chr(34)
```

Read more about that in the [Filtering Items Using a String Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering-items-using-a-string-comparison) article.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway still not working. 

I'm trying some different names from my contact folder.
Sometimes found, sometimes no. Not sure why.

i.e. Found   John Doe    as FullName.
But then if searching Doe, nothing is found (?).

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to resolve a name, try `Application.Session.CreateRecipient("John Doe")` / `Recipient.Resolve`.